# How can I capture an array of objects that are generated by the user?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am trying to capture an array of objects that are generated by the user.  My problem is that though the array is generated, the objects fail to retain any values entered by the user, thus populating the array with objects that have null properties.

Here is the code.
Javascript:

```
// add additional employment
$scope.addEmployment = function() {

    $scope.AdditionalEmployment.push(
        {
            AddEmploymentStatusId: '',
            EmploymentTypeId: '',
            EmployerName: '',
            EmploymentStartDate: '',
            EmploymentEndDate: '',
            EmployerNumber: '',
            EmployerStAddress: '',
            EmployerCity: '',
            EmployerState: ''
        }
    );

};

$scope.saveApplication = function() {

    // create post obj
    var postObj = {

        AdditionalEmployment: $scope.AdditionalEmployment

    };

    // api post
    $http.post('/api/Employment/JobHistory', postObj)
        .success(function(data) {
            // success code

        })
        .error(function(data) {
            // error code
        });

};
```

HTML:

```
<fieldset class="FormBackground3">
                    <legend class="FormBackground3">Additional Employment</legend>
                    <div ng-repeat="x in AdditionalEmployment" class="text-center">
                        <h3>{{$index + 1}}</h3>
                        <!--Employment Status-->
                        <div class="form-group" style="display: inline-block;">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></i>
                            <label for="{{'empStatId' + $index}}" class="control-label">
                                Employment Status
                            </label>
                            <select class="form-control"
                                    ng-model="x[$index].EmploymentStatusId" id="{{'empStatId' +  $index}}"
                                    ng-options="x.Id as x.Status for x in Statuses.Employment">
                                <option value="">--Select--</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>

                        <!--Employment Type-->
                        <div class="form-group" style="display: inline-block;">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-asterisk"></i>
                            <label for="{{'empTypeId' + $index}}" class="control-label">
                                Employment Type
                            </label>
                            <select class="form-control"
                                    ng-model="x[$index].EmploymentTypeId" id="{{'empTypeId' + $index}}"
                                    ng-options="x.Id as x.Type for x in Statuses.EmploymentType">
                                <option value="">--Select--</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>

                        <!--Employer-->
                        <div class="form-group" style="display: inline-block;">
                            <label for="{{'emplyId' + $index}}" class="control-label">
                                Employer Name
                            </label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control"
                                   ng-model="x[$index].EmployerName" id="{{'emplyId' + $index}}" />
                        </div>

                        <!--Employment Start Date-->
                        <div class="form-group" style="display: inline-block;">
                            <label for="{{'empStartId' + $index}}" class="control-label">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
                                Employment Start Date
                            </label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control"
                                   ng-model="x[$index].EmploymentStartDate" id="{{'empStartId' + $index}}" bs-datepicker />
                        </div>

                        <!--Employment End Date-->
                        <div class="form-group" style="display: inline-block;">
                            <label for="{{'empEndId' + $index}}" class="control-label">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
                                Employment End Date
                            </label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control"
                                   ng-model="x[$index].EmploymentEndDate" id="{{'empEndId' + $index}}" bs-datepicker />
                        </div>

                        <!--Employer Number-->
                        <div class="form-group" style="display: inline-block;">
                            <label for="{{'empNumId' + $index}}" class="control-label">
                                Employer Phone Number
                            </label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control"
                                   ng-model="x[$index].EmployerNumber" id="{{'empNumId' + $index}}" />
                        </div>

                        <!--Employer St Address-->
                        <div class="form-group" style="display: inline-block;">
                            <label for="{{'empStId' + $index}}" class="control-label">
                                Employer St Address
                            </label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control"
                                   ng-model="x[$index].EmployerStAddress" id="{{'empStId' + $index}}" />
                        </div>

                        <!--Employment City-->
                        <div class="form-group" style="display: inline-block;">
                            <label for="{{'empCityId' + $index}}" class="control-label">
                                Employer City
                            </label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control"
                                   ng-model="x[$index].EmployerCity" id="{{'empCityId' + $index}}" />
                        </div>

                        <!--Employment State-->
                        <div class="form-group" style="display: inline-block;">
                            <label for="{{'empStateId' + $index}}" class="control-label">
                                Employer State
                            </label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control"
                                   ng-model="x[$index].EmployerState" id="{{'empStateId' + $index}}" />
                        </div>

                        <!--Remove employment-->
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <button ng-click="removeEmployment($index)">
                                Remove
                            </button>
                        </div>


                    </div>
                    <div class="text-center" style="padding: 7px;">
                        <button ng-click="addEmployment()" class="btn btn-info btn-xs">
                            Add Additional Employment
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </fieldset> 

<button ng-click="saveApplication()" class="btn btn-warning">
                        Submit
                    </button>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: @EliteOctagon: " <button ng-click="addEmployment()" "

Comment: ah, in the html. why dont you pass some parameters to it and see if they show up in the console?

Comment: It's at the bottom, scroll down please.

Comment: how are you assigning values? your function just assigns blank strings to each variable in the object being pushed.

Comment: I assumed the values would be updated by the user.  I am obviously missing something.

Comment: When `saveApplication` gets triggered?

Comment: try this out... do console.log($scope.AdditionalEmployment) right at the beginning of addEmployment(), see what object prints out

Comment: @bebraw yes.  Sorry, I forgot to add the saveApplication() button which is further down in the actual HTML.

Comment: an editable plunker of jsfiddle would help out I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your ng-model to not include the [$index]. It seems you are repeating on an array of objects and then trying to access the numerical index of an object.

I think you were assigning it to:

```
{ 1: field one, 2: field 2 ... }
```

Ex:

```
ng-model="x.EmploymentStatusId"
```

I think that was the issue.